# How to allocate memory for an object I don't know the real type of? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, contains, derived-class

I want to store an object of some derived class as a property of another object.

The problem for me is to know the size of the object to be stored, as it can be any derived class of a given base class. I cannot just allocate memory for the base class' object, right, as it's smaller. I suppose, *typeof* operator would also just give the size of the base class, right?

Here is my sample code. Please, see the comments to understand what I mean. Excuse me for the unoriginality…

```
BaseA {};

DerivedA1 : BaseA {public: void property() { cout << 1; }};
DerivedA2 : BaseA {public: void property() { cout << 2; }};
// etc. - several derived classes.

BaseB   // Contains (or links to) an instance of class derived from BaseA.
{
public:
    BaseA * instanceA;

    BaseB (BaseA instanceAX)
    {
        // ??? => How to allocate memory for the object
        // I don't know the real type of?
        instanceA = new BaseA (instanceAX);
    }

    BaseB (BaseA instanceAX) { delete instanceA; }
};

main()
{
    DerivedA1 instanceA1;
    BaseB instanceB (instanceA1);

    // Use "property" regardless of which derived class it belongs to.
    instanceB.instanceA->property();
}
```

I could store a pointer instead of the object itself, it would be easier. But I'm not sure I want to rely on the caller to retain the property object for the life of instance *instanceB*.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us the bigger picture about what you want to do. The intentions in the above code do not look like the correct approach and the design should be reconsidered. Perhaps we can help with that.

Comment: @T33C: Well, _BaseB_ is a class (which in turn have its own derived classes) for managing schedulers and _BaseA_ is a tool that _BaseB_ uses to add custom data and build the final schedules. The logic of the tool is brought out of _BaseB_, that's why the caller (another class) knows to pass the right tool to the right scheduler, so it can get exactly the schedules from _BaseB_ it needs. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, since you pass in your BaseA by value, and not by reference or pointer, you DO know the type; it's BaseA.  BaseB was copied into a BaseA and that BaseA copy is sent to the function.  Any extra data in BaseB is not contained in instanceAX.  This is called "slicing".

But, to answer your question, you simply do not do it this way.  You need a clone() function in your BaseB class if it is meant to work this way.  Alternatively you might design a smart pointer or other object that can clone the instance for you.  If you search for my name on comp.lang.c++ along with clone() you might come across a discussion I had there about this latter idea.

The clone function is of course a virtual function that returns a copy of the current object:

```
struct BaseA
{
  virtual BaseA* clone() const = 0;
};

struct BaseB : BaseA
{
  BaseB* clone() const { return new BaseB(*this); }
};
```

Comment: Roberts: I suppose that you mixed BaseB with BaseA1 (probably due to the poor class naming on my part…), but I think I understand your idea. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities.

- Give `BaseA` a purely virtual member function, maybe called `clone`, that is responsible to generate a copy of the instance it is called on. Then the constructor of `BaseB` might become

  `BaseB (BaseA const &instanceAX) { instanceA = instanceAX.clone (); }`
- You could also just avoid passing raw pointers around and use `boost::shared_ptr` instead. This way, since it is reference-counted, your caller can't cause a premature destruction of the `BaseA` derivation that was used to construct `BaseB`. You'd have to adjust `BaseA * instanceA;` to read `boost::shared_ptr <BaseA> instanceA;` Then `BaseB`'s constructor might look like:

  `BaseB (boost::shared_ptr <BaseA> a) : instanceA (a) { }`

The problem of the first aproach is that some client programmer that inherits from, say `DerivedA1` may forget to implement `clone` in his derivation. The principal problem of the second aproach would be to require every user of `BaseB` to allocate the property object on the heap (Since you are making a copy inside `BaseB`s constructor anyway, at least the total memory consumption would not rise, though)

Comment: Use of virtual inheritance can be used to make sure the most derived class implements clone(): http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_thread/thread/c01181365d327b2f/9c99f46a8a64242e?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=comp.lang.c%2B%2B+noah+roberts+clone&pli=1

Comment: I also wouldn't recommend the shared_ptr for return from clone().  You should consider clone() a factory function (even though it's a "Prototype") and you don't want to force all creations into a shared_ptr.  You want the client (the code trying to create the object) to decide what kind of ownership rules it needs (usually) and if you return a shared_ptr they simply cannot--there's no way to release the pointer without destroying it.  Use of auto_ptr or unique_ptr is better for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Noah Roberts. Thanks. I meant `shared_ptr` as argument to `BaseB`'s constructor, not as return value from `clone`. In fact, `clone` would then not be necessary to have.

Comment: Thank you both for the other option and considerations on choosing the right one! I think I'll use the first possibility for now, as apart from other things, it sounds simpler to me. :)